# Bounds on the size of the normal neighbourhood

Tags: general-relativity, topology

One of the most important feature of general relativity is the existence of the convex normal neighbourhood, a neighbourhood $U$ on which the exponential map is a diffeomorphism between $\exp^{-1}(U)$ and $U$. A lot of the so-called "locally Minkowski" arguments are based on this fact.

But as far as I'm aware, I can't think of any indication of the *size* of a normal neighbourhood, which could indicate up to what sort of scale we could assume, without fear of contradiction, that the spacetime can roughly be considered like Minkowski space. Obviously Minkowski space itself can have the entire spacetime as a normal neighbourhood, while considering some kind of Wheeler-style spacetime foam, microscopic wormholes would render that size very small.

Does there exist some kind of estimate of the diameter of such a neighbourhood? This is a bit tricky to define in a Lorentzian manifold of course, but let's say for instance something of the form, for a given timelike curve $\gamma$, the greatest cylinder such that every proper time in $[\tau_1, \tau_2]$, and every point at a distance $< R$ from this curve are inside the neighbourhood. Are there any conditions on the curvature or stress energy tensor that could help to determine this?

Comment: I am being told by the math people that this is the injectivity radius, so this may be relevant : https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612860